# nested loops to IDataReader

Tags: c#

I have a program that writes a huge `DataTable` (2.000.000 to 70.000.000 rows, depends on the configuration) to a database using a `SqlBulkCopy`.

I decided to change the loop that populates this table into a `IDataReader`, because the amount of rows often causes an `OutOfMemoryException`.

The table is populated like this

```
// int[] firsts;
// string[] seconds;
// byte[] thirds;
var table = new DataTable();
foreach(var f in firsts)
{
    foreach(var s in seconds)
    {
        foreach(var t in thirds)
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            row[0] = f;
            row[1] = s;
            row[2] = t;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
    // here I also bulk load the table and clear it
}
```

so in my `IDataReader` class I will loop by index. This is my attempt.

```
class TableReader : IDataReader
{
    bool Eof = false;

    int FirstIndex;
    int SecondIndex;
    int ThirdIndex;

    //those are populated via constructor
    int[] firsts;
    string[] seconds;
    byte[] thirds;

    // this will be retrieved automatically via indexer
    object[] Values;

    public bool Read()
    {
        if(ThirdIndex != thirds.Length
            && SecondIndex < seconds.Length
            && FirstIndex < firsts.Length)
        {
            Values[0] = firsts[FirstIndex];
            Values[1] = seconds[SecondIndex];
            Values[2] = thirds[ThirdIndex++];
        }
        else if(SecondIndex != seconds.Length)
        {
            ThirdIndex  = 0;
            SecondIndex++;
        }
        else if(FirstIndex != firsts.Length)
        {
            SecondIndex = 0;
            FirstIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            Eof = true;
        }
        return !Eof;
    }
}
```

I've created this code using a `while(true)` loop with a break instead of the `Eof`, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Anyone can help?

Comment: And do you really need to have all the 70.000.000 rows in memory at the same time? Sounds like a design problem to me

Comment: Why not use multiple data tables? Break it out.

Comment: Do you have to populate the entire table in one go, or can you split it up into smaller transfers requiring less memory?

Comment: edited the question with the current (functioning) fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually possible if you implement IDataReader and use the "yield return" keyword to provide rows.  IDataReader is a bit of a pain to implement, but it isn't complex at all.  The code below can be adapted to load a terabyte worth of data to the database and never run out of memory.

- I replaced the DataRow objects with a single object array that is reused throughout the data read.
- Because there's no DataTable object to represent the columns, I had to do this myself by storing the data types and column names separately.

  ```
  class TestDataReader : IDataReader {
      int[] firsts = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
      string[] seconds = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
      byte[] thirds = { 0x30, 0x31, 0x32 };

      // The data types of each column.
      Type[] dataTypes = { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(byte) };

      // The names of each column.
      string[] names = { "firsts", "seconds", "thirds" };

      // This function uses coroutines to turn the "push" approach into a "pull" approach.
      private IEnumerable<object[]> GetRows() {
          // Just re-use the same array. 
          object[] row = new object[3];
          foreach (var f in firsts) {
              foreach (var s in seconds) {
                  foreach (var t in thirds) {
                      row[0] = f;
                      row[1] = s;
                      row[2] = t;
                      yield return row;
                  }
              }
              // here I also bulk load he table and clear it
          }
      }


      // Everything below basically wraps this.
      IEnumerator<object[]> rowProvider;

      public TestDataReader() {
          rowProvider = GetRows().GetEnumerator();
      }

      public object this[int i] {
          get {
              return GetValue(i);
          }
      }

      public object this[string name] {
          get {
              return GetValue(GetOrdinal(name));
          }
      }

      public int  Depth                       { get { return 0;                               } }
      public int  FieldCount                  { get { return dataTypes.Length;                } }
      public bool IsClosed                    { get { return false;                           } }
      public int  RecordsAffected             { get { return 0;                               } }

      // These don't really do anything.
      public void Close()                     { Dispose();                                    }
      public void Dispose()                   { rowProvider.Dispose();                        }

      public string   GetDataTypeName(int i)  { return dataTypes[i].Name;                     }
      public Type     GetFieldType(int i)     { return dataTypes[i];                          }

      // These functions get basic data types.
      public bool     GetBoolean(int i)       { return (bool)     rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public byte     GetByte(int i)          { return (byte)     rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public char     GetChar(int i)          { return (char)     rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public DateTime GetDateTime(int i)      { return (DateTime) rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public decimal  GetDecimal(int i)       { return (decimal)  rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public double   GetDouble(int i)        { return (double)   rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public float    GetFloat(int i)         { return (float)    rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public Guid     GetGuid(int i)          { return (Guid)     rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public short    GetInt16(int i)         { return (short)    rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public int      GetInt32(int i)         { return (int)      rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public long     GetInt64(int i)         { return (long)     rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public string   GetString(int i)        { return (string)   rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public object   GetValue(int i)         { return (object)   rowProvider.Current[i];     }
      public string   GetName(int i)          { return names[i];                              }

      public bool IsDBNull(int i) {
          object obj = rowProvider.Current[i];
          return obj == null || obj is DBNull;
      }

      // Looks up a field number given its name.
      public int GetOrdinal(string name) {
          return Array.FindIndex(names, x => x.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
      }

      // Populate "values" given the current row of data.
      public int GetValues(object[] values) {
          if (values == null) {
              return 0;
          } else {
              int len = Math.Min(values.Length, rowProvider.Current.Length);
              Array.Copy(rowProvider.Current, values, len);
              return len;
          }
      }

      // This reader only supports a single result set.
      public bool NextResult() {
          return false;
      }

      // Move to the next row.
      public bool Read() {
          return rowProvider.MoveNext();
      }

      // Don't bother implementing these in any meaningful way.
      public long GetBytes(int i, long fieldOffset, byte[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length) {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public long GetChars(int i, long fieldoffset, char[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length) {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public IDataReader GetData(int i) {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public DataTable GetSchemaTable() {
          return null;
      }

  }
  ```